# Access Input id from the include page in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to fetch the 'id1' mentioned on the different file. I have included the file using the include function. But does not get success. Can you please let me know where i am making mistake. Or is there another way to access this field

The detail is there underbelow

I have this text field in one file (file1.php) `<input id ="id1" type = text" value ="location">`

I have another file (file2.php), where i include the above file as `<?php include("file1.php"); ?>`

How can i access the 'id1' using document.getElementbyId. in file2.php

When i use it directly as document.getElementbyId('id1').value; its not coming.. Please help

Comment: Use session to include the ID

Comment: The problem is that Javascript is case sensitive, and you're trying to use a method that doesn't exist. Your `B` should be uppercase: `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Buzinas Oh, Its a silly mistake.. Thanks for your answer. Can you send your comment as answer.. i'll mark it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Javascript is case sensitive, and you're trying to use a method that doesn't exist.

Your `B` should be uppercase: `document.getElementById`